# How to access class variables in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I would like to access the variables declared in a class in a function in the same class. For example, in C++, the code would look like,

```
// Header
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(int input);
        ~Foo();
        void bar();
        int a, b;
}

// Implementation
Foo::Foo(int input)
{
    a = input;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
}

void Foo::bar()
{
    b = a/2;
}

// Usage
#include <Foo.h>

int main()
{
    int input = 6;
    Foo test_class(input);

    // Access class variable
    std::cout << test_class.b << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am confused how to get the same functionality in MATLAB. So far, I have done:

```
% Class 'm' file
classdef Foo

    properties
        a;
        b;
        output;
    end

    methods
        % Class constructor
        function obj = Foo(input)
            obj.a = input;
            obj.b = obj.a/2;
        end

        % Another function where I want access to 'b'
        function output = bar(obj)
            output = ( obj.b + obj.a )/2;
        end
    end

end

% Usage
input = 6;
foo = Foo(input);

result = foo.bar(); %MATLAB complains here
```

I have also tried putting `bar()` as a **Static method** but to no avail. Any help will be much appreciated.!

Cheers.!

UPDATE: The code above actually does work as expected and the error I was getting was totally unrelated to anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, in Matlab R2013a, `foo = Foo(input)` is already an error: Matlab expects the constructor to be called `Foo`,  not `constructor`—and that one input parameter is one too many for the default constructor.  If I rename your method `constructor` to `Foo` then it works and I get `result` equal to `4.5` as intended.

Comment: Oops.! That was a typo in the program I pasted here (my original is too long to put up here). I have changed it accordingly. 

Actually, the error in my program was pretty stupid. It was an image processing problem and I was trying to use c++ syntax; but MATLAB was giving a weird error for it. Anyway, thanks.!